# How to use AvroSerializer without a schema registry

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I am trying to write a unit test that verifies that adding a new property to an Avro schema is backwards compatible.

First I took the Avro generated .cs model and saved it as MyModelOld.cs and renamed the class inside to MyModelOld.
Then I re-ran Avro gen against the avsc file with the new property.

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
var schemaRegistry = -> something that doesn't require a running docker image <-;
var deserializerOld = new AvroDeserializer<MyModelOld>(schemaRegistry);
var serializerNew = new AvroSerializer<MyModel>(schemaRegistry);

var myModel = new MyModel() {...};
var myModelBytes = await serializerNew.SerializeAsync(myModel, new());

var myModelOld = await deserializerOld.DeserializeAsync(myModelBytes, false, new());
// Check properties...
```

Then I was going to go the opposite direction and check that the new property uses the specified default value.

The problem I'm having is what to use for the schema registry.  I don't want to have a docker image running for these tests because I don't think it shouldn't be necessary.

I've tried a mock of `ISchemaRegistry`, but it appears to need a fully functional class in order for serialize/deserialize to work.

I could probably walk through the logic for `CachedSchemaRegistryClient` and try to munge it to work, but before I do so I'd like to find out if someone knows of an `ISchemaRegistry` implementaion that would work for my use case.

Has anyone tried to write tests to validate backwards compatibility of Avro schema updates?

If so, how did you go about doing so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing it this way:

```
private ISchemaRegistryClient NewTestRegistry(string topic)
{
    // Code to mock SchemaRegistry taken from:
    // https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/test/Confluent.SchemaRegistry.Serdes.UnitTests/SerializeDeserialize.cs
    Dictionary<string, int> store = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    var schemaRegistryMock = new Mock<ISchemaRegistryClient>();

#pragma warning disable CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
    schemaRegistryMock.Setup(x => x.ConstructValueSubjectName(topic, It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Returns($"{topic}-value");

    schemaRegistryMock.Setup(x => x.RegisterSchemaAsync($"{topic}-value", It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<bool>()))
        .ReturnsAsync((string topic, string schema, bool normalize) => 
            store.TryGetValue(schema, out int id) ? id : store[schema] = store.Count + 1
        );
#pragma warning restore CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete

    schemaRegistryMock.Setup(x => x.GetSchemaAsync(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
        .ReturnsAsync((int id, string format) => 
            new Schema(store.Where(x => x.Value == id).First().Key, null, SchemaType.Avro)
        );

    return schemaRegistryMock.Object;
}

[TestMethod]
public async Task BackwardsCompatible()
{
    var topic = "MyCoolTopic";
    var schemaRegistry = NewTestRegistry(topic);
    var context = new SerializationContext(MessageComponentType.Value, topic);

    var deserializerOld = new AvroDeserializer<MyModelOld>(schemaRegistry);
    var serializerNew = new AvroSerializer<MyModel>(schemaRegistry);

    var myModel = new MyModel() { /* Set properties */};
    var myModelBytes = await serializerNew.SerializeAsync(myModel, context);

    var myModelOld = await deserializerOld.DeserializeAsync(myModelBytes, false, context);
    // Check properties...
}

[TestMethod]
public async Task ForwardsCompatible() 
{ 
    // Similar to the above test. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test schemas, you don't need Kafka-related serializers; just use raw Avro C# library.

Alternatively, look at the [existing tests](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/test/Confluent.SchemaRegistry.UnitTests/CachedSchemaRegistryClient.cs#L42)

```
var config = new SchemaRegistryConfig { Url = "irrelevanthost:8081" };
var src = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(config);
Assert...(src... );
```